# Multiple string literals in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Accidentally met something strange.

`SELECT * from tablename WHERE mytext LIKE '%string1%' '%1234%';`

works absolutely equal to

`SELECT * from tablename WHERE mytext LIKE '%string1%' AND mytext LIKE '%1234%';`

Something wrong with me, my code or I just didn't knew about it and couldn't find it in docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String literals are automatically concatenated, as explained [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html).

For instance, `'hello' 'world'` is equivalent to the single literal `'helloworld'`

Thus, when you write:

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE mytext LIKE '%string1%' '%1234%';
```

... that is actually equivalent to writing:

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE mytext LIKE '%string1%%1234%';
```

As you noted, that is somewhat similar to:

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE mytext LIKE '%string1%' AND mytext LIKE '%1234%';
```

... but not exactly. Indeed, the former would match `'string1 1234'` but *not* `'1234 string1'`.

Try the following example to verify this:

```
create table tablename(
  pkey bigint,
  mytext varchar(64)
);

insert into tablename values (1, 'a b'), (2, 'a c'), (3, 'b a');
select * from tablename where mytext like '%a%' '%b%'; -- returns 1 row
select * from tablename where mytext like '%a%' and mytext like '%b%'; -- returns two rows
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need.